# Virtual Page scrolling in jqGrid in IE9

Tags: internet-explorer, jqgrid

Can anyone point me to a fix or show me how can virtual scrolling be achieved in jqGrid with large datasets with IE 9 as the browser. It works in Chrome, Firefox but IE 9, the functionality is not working.

Comment: What do you mean "not working"? How large is your data set?

Comment: Are you sure you really need a user to scroll through 50K rows? Would a pager be more appropriate?

Comment: The requirement is to disable paging and I'm struggling

Comment: I love it when you ask something and instead of answering or ignoring,  people starts to blame your entire life!